# Cakephp: How can display\use View in Plugin

Tags: cakephp, plugins, controller, view, overriding

I created a Plugin and in Plugin have Controler, Model,View... At app/Controller I made TestController extend Plugin Controller . but i can't use View of Plugin. How must I do?

Comment: why don't you use ajax to call that view of the plugin !!!

Comment: Plugin is small application, to display view you need route for controller for example `http://example.com/plugin_name/controller/action`